# The anchor element doesn't recognized on specify positions with tag helpers .Net core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working with .Net Core 6 and currently I have problems to make it works the  elements with tag helpers.

```
<div class="container p-3">
<div class="row pt-4">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Category List</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-end">
        <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp; Create new category
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-primary" ">
            <th scope="row">Category Name</th>
            <th scope="row">Display Order</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var category in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">@category.Name</td>
                <td width="30%">@category.DisplayOrder</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                        <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@category.Id" class="btn btn-primary mx-2">
                            <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here the first anchor works perfectly,

```
<a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">
   <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp; Create new category
</a>
```

But when I'm using the next one, and I run the application, the navigator does not recognize the tag and does not create automatically the sintax to add the href tag.

```
<a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@category.Id" class="btn btn-primary mx-2">
                                <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit
                            </a>
```

Comment: BTW, your `<th scope="row">` should be `<th scope="col">`.

Comment: Does your `CategoryController` **actually** have an action named `Edit` that accepts an `Int32 id` route-parameter?

Comment: Sorry, Yes it does, I have the action called Edit that received a parameter Int32 id. But in that position, the anchor element is not renderized with the href tag. If I manually add the property href="Category/Edit/@category.Id" to the anchor element, it works, but using tag helpers still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, I finally found the reason.

The problem is with this line of code:

```
<tr class="table-primary" ">
```

It has one more `"`.

Remove it, the href will be displayed normally.

```
<tr class="table-primary">
```

[image]

Comment: No way, I dind't see that. I changed it and now it works. Thank you